# Undefined reference to boost::python::detail::init_module and friends

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, boost-python

I am trying to test boost python with example in official website.
But It incurs so many errors...
The below is my what i did and the errors.

1. Download Boost1.55 with [this](http://choorucode.com/2013/12/27/how-to-upgrade-the-boost-library-on-ubuntu/).
2. Add `Eclipse` library search path to "usr/includ" (boost directory place at here)
3. Add library flag `-lpython2.7` (Python2.7 is installed)
4. Add include path `usr/include/python2.7`(at my first try, the error happen : couldn't find `pyconfig.h`)

And this is my test code i did, and errors, the test code was only to see if it is compiled normally with boost python.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "aaa" << std::endl;
}
```

.
The Error part denoted with redline in eclipse is `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)`

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project tsetBoost ****

make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: tsetBoost
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/include -o"tsetBoost"  ./main.o   -lpython2.7
./main.o: In function `inithello_ext':
/home/kim/workspace/tsetBoost/Debug/../main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)())'
./main.o: In function `boost::python::type_info::name() const':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/type_id.hpp:165: undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::gcc_demangle(char const*)'
./main.o: In function `boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::operator()(char const* const&) const':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/builtin_converters.hpp:161: undefined reference to `boost::python::converter::do_return_to_python(char const*)'
./main.o: In function `void boost::python::def<char const* (*)()>(char const*, char const* (*)())':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/def.hpp:91: undefined reference to `boost::python::detail::scope_setattr_doc(char const*, boost::python::api::object const&, char const*)'
./main.o: In function `boost::python::api::object boost::python::detail::make_function_aux<char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> >(char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies const&, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/make_function.hpp:38: undefined reference to `boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&)'
./main.o: In function `py_function_impl_base':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:20: undefined reference to `vtable for boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base'
./main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE[vtable for boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> > >]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::max_arity() const'
./main.o: In function `~caller_py_function_impl':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:30: undefined reference to `boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::~py_function_impl_base()'
./main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFPKcvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IS6_EEEEEE[typeinfo for boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<char const* (*)(), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector1<char const*> > >]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base'
./main.o: In function `boost::python::converter::expected_pytype_for_arg<char const*>::get_pytype()':
/usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:68: undefined reference to `boost::python::converter::registry::query(boost::python::type_info)'
/usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/pytype_function.hpp:69: undefined reference to `boost::python::converter::registration::expected_from_python_type() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tsetBoost] ERROR 1
```

Comment: Looks like you're not linking against something you need.

Comment: On your linker command line, you're adding /usr/include to the linker path. That's most likely wrong and you need to add the correct path.

Comment: what is correct path you are saying, i just set the path because i saw a tutorial on boost with eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added two additional flags for boost and then it works !!

```
-lboost_python -lboost_system
```

Comment: Is there any document said about add this two flags, I have read the official    boost.python tutorial but not find it .http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html