# boost python error undefined symbol boost::python::detail::gcc_demangle(char const*)

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake, g++

I'm trying to run a [code](https://github.com/Isdriai/packet2vec), for that, I have to compile a shared librairy with cmake and boost. The tuto says I have to do:

```
cd ParallelPcap
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make parallelpcap
```

Firstly, I had issues with the CmakeLists.txt when I was doing cmake, indeed I had to put

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED unit_test_framework program_options 
                        system python numpy filesystem serialization)
```

instead of

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED unit_test_framework program_options 
                        system python3 numpy3 filesystem serialization)
```

and instead of

```
cmake ..
```

I did

```
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/easybuild/software/2020/avx2/Core/python/3.8.2/bin/python" ..
```

After the make and mv commands, I tried to run my code and I have

```
python3 main.py run -c packet2vec_config.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pcaps.process as pp
  File "/project/6045847/ropic/packet2vec/pcaps/process.py", line 1, in <module>
    import parallelpcap
ImportError: /project/6045847/ropic/packet2vec/parallelpcap.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc
```

for more readable error, I did this command

```
c++filt -n _ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc
boost::python::detail::gcc_demangle(char const*)
```

After researching, I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481872/linking-error-with-boost-python-while-compiling) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328423/undefined-reference-to-boostpythondetailinit-module-and-friends/26331847).

So I put in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -ftree-vectorize -msse2 -fopt-info-vec-optimized -lboost_python38 -lboost_system")
```

instead of

```
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -ftree-vectorize -msse2 -fopt-info-vec-optimized -lboost_python38 -lboost_system")
```

(I added -lboost_python38 and -lboost_system flags in the CMaleLists.txt)

But I have the same issue when I run my code

I have huge outputs when I do cmake and make so I'm not sure if it's necessary that I share them

EDIT: When I do a research (with the term "#include <boost/") I have the following result:

```
ReadPcap.hpp

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

CountDictionnary.hpp

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

Packet.hpp

#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

Pacekt2Vec.hpp

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

Pcap.hpp

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

TestPcap.hpp

#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

Util.hpp

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_free.hpp>


ParallelPcapExt.cpp

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```

Does this mean I need to add libraries as build options in my CMakeLists.txt ?
Or can the code run with my current compiler options (more precisely -lboost_python38 and -lboost_system flags) ?

EDIT2: I tried to add -lboost_serialization -lboost_filesystem flags to my CMakeLists.txt like -lboost_python38 and -lboost_system without success. I still have the same error when I run the code